# XSL iterate elements of same tag

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I'm learning XSD, and I tried to transform XML in HTML with bad results until now.
I have this XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sales>
  <division id="North">
    <revenue>10</revenue>
    <growth>9</growth>
    <bonus>7</bonus>
  </division>
  <division id="South">
    <revenue>4</revenue>
    <growth>3</growth>
    <bonus>4</bonus>
    </division>
  <division id="West">
    <revenue>6</revenue>
    <growth>-1.5</growth>
    <bonus>2</bonus>
  </division>
</sales>
```

With XSL I want this:

[image: Expected Results]

This is my XSL code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="/sales">
    <table border = "1" >
      <tr>
         <th>Division</th>
         <th>Revenue</th>
         <th>Growth</th>
         <th>Bonus</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:apply-templates select ="/sales/division"/>   
    </table>  
  </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="/sales/division">
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select ="/sales/division/@id"/> </td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select ="/sales/division/revenue"/> </td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select ="/sales/division/growth"/> </td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select ="/sales/division/bonus"/> </td>
    </tr>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And I obtain this:

[image: Results]

I tried also with:

```
<xsl:for-each select ="/sales/division" >
 <tr>
  <td><xsl:value-of select ="/sales/division/@id"/> </td>
  <td><xsl:value-of select ="/sales/division/revenue"/> </td>
  <td><xsl:value-of select ="/sales/division/growth"/> </td>
  <td><xsl:value-of select ="/sales/division/bonus"/> </td>
 </tr>
```

But I have same bad result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want XSL like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="sales"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="sales">
        <table border = "1" >
           <tr>
               <th>Division</th>
               <th>Revenue</th>
               <th>Growth</th>
               <th>Bonus</th>
           </tr>
           <xsl:apply-templates select ="division"/>   
        </table>  
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="division">
        <tr>
            <td><xsl:value-of select ="@id"/> </td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select ="revenue"/> </td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select ="growth"/> </td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select ="bonus"/> </td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

That will yeild a result like:

[image: Result]

You are using [absolute](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/xpath/xpath_absolute_path.htm) paths all the time rather than [relative](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/xpath/xpath_relative_path.htm) ones to the **current node**.

By using an absolute path like `/sales/division/@id` it would always pick the first one. Once you understand the concept of *absolute* vs. *relative* you should be fine.

---

Note that you stated in the question that you desired them to be listed *North, West, South* but that is not the order of the elements in the file.

Comment: Great, could you suggest to me a good website to know about the difference?

Comment: I have provided hyperlinks to two tutorials. Hopefully they will help.